# Ckeditor remains hidden after creation - editor.css is empty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tinymce, ckeditor, webapp2

I am trying to use ckeditor in a web project I am currently developing.

The problem is that when I try to instantiate the Ckeditor (either via the jQuery adapter or with the CKEDITOR.replace command), the editor is created but it is hidden.

I inspected the source code and for some reason it has this css attribute

```
.cke_skin_kama {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then I checked the css files that it uses and I noticed that the editor.css file has no css rule in it! It's completely empty, although it points to the correct url.

Do you know why this is happening? Any hint would be more than welcome!

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I tried to use Tinymce also, but I have the same problem. The file ui.css is empty too.

I am using python-webapp2 for GAE. Could this have any relation to the problem? Any specific configuration I have to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably lies in the declaration of your static files directories. Try to move ckeditor outside the paths of your existing static files. For example add the following in your app.yaml, and of course place the ckeditor in the respective folder:

```
- url: /ckeditor
  static_dir: static/ckeditor
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want create chkeditor into your page you can use this code after attaching chkeditor javascript file :

```
<textarea  id='chkeditor2' class='ckeditor' name='editor1'></textarea>
```

class and name is defined into javascript file and this text area will chkeditor panel. sorry for bad english :) i hope this will helpfull for you :)

Comment: The ckeditor is created. The problem is that the editor.css file is empty for some reason.

Comment: Did you check the debugger (Chrome Developer Tools) if the CSS request has errors?

Comment: But does it show your CSS in the developer tools? Do you receive the CSS?